# globals() - _frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, global

I did `globals()` in Idle and saw `_frozen_importlib.BuiltinImporter`.  Can anyone aid with an explanation or a reference source?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's [`importlib.machinery.BuiltinImporter`](http://docs.python.org/3/library/importlib#importlib.machinery.BuiltinImporter), the importer for built-in modules. The core of importlib is [bootstrapped](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/62cf4e77f785/Lib/importlib/_bootstrap.py) as a [frozen module](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/62cf4e77f785/Python/importlib.h) in the interpreter.